# allan-variance noise terms of MEMS accelerometer

Tags: electrical-engineering, sensors, noise

Specific noise terms are given in datasheets of MEMS sensors.
In example the specification of accelerometer contains information about random walk and in some cases the bias instability.

- Both quantities are determined by computing the allan varianz and allan deviation.
  The result of the allan deviation consists out of more noise terms than random walk and bias stability.

  - Why are only random walk and bias instability mentioned in datasheets?
  - Are those the terms that cause most noise?
    If yes why?
- One more thing:
  Different noise errors are represented by different slopes of allan deviation.
- Is it like a characteristic of allan deviation that different slopes occur after calculating a specific amount of overlapping clusters (groups of samples)?

**Reference:**

- [Allan Variance: Noise Analysis for Gyroscopes](https://telesens.co/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/AllanVariance5087-1.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for the noise term used here is that the MEMS sensor used already causes a noise. Allan varianz and Allan deviation calculations all add up to noise in the sensor. The biggest sources of noise on the system are these two factors.

I can answer the other question as follows. It is not possible to consider overlapping sets as a property of Allan deviation. While sample sets are used for high data analysis, you can do noise analysis with Allan deviation. You can take measurements of the generated noise.